# How can I take a simple data output in Python and export it to a an excel (or notepad)?

Tags: python, excel, opencv

I'm working on a project that involves Python. I've NEVER used it along with OpenCV. The objective is to take a 16x16 section of an video, I'm practicing with a single Image, and get it's RBG value. I'm suppose to run this for thousands of frame on a video, which i dont know how to loop. Once I have it ([ 71 155  90]) for example, I want to save it to a notepad, excel sheet, or some simple way or referring to my results.

I've tried looking up tutorials on how to export values, but they've used so many different terms that I don't know where to start.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('dog.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

px = img[16,16]

print(px)
```

The only thing I get is the RBG output [ 71 155  90] in the terminal. I don't know where to do from there. I don't know how to export the value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or

```
import numpy as np import cv2
img = cv2.imread('dog.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
px = img[16,16]

import pandas as px
df = pd.DataFrame(px)
df.to_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to open a file and then write the results to that file, here is one possible way to do this (although perhaps not the most optimal):

```
 fp = open('output.csv', 'w')
 fp.write('{},{},{}'.format(px[0],px[1],px[2])
 # write more values here
 fp.close()  # do this at the end of your writes
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on something similar, instead of videos I am working with images so I went around searching for tutorials on how to do bulk export of images/ frames from a folder and saving the data into a numpy array.
This is a sample of my code *not sure how much errors are inside but it is able to load and save image frames into an array. I use tqdm to show a simple progress bar so I know what is the status of the image loading when I call this function.

```
def img_readph(path):
readph =[i for i in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path,i))]
img = np.empty(len(readph), dtype=object)
for j in tqdm(range(0, len(readph))):
    img[j] = cv2.imread(join(path,readph[j]))
return img
```

In order to load and work on the images that are currently saved in a numpy array stack, I use this set of code to do the extraction, perform a basic psnr calculation and save the data to a .txt (learning how to convert the result to a .csv that I can load/save/append in python for future edits as well).

```
for index in tqdm(range(len(img))):
        (psnr, meanerror) = calculate_psnr(imgGT[index], imgSR[index])
        print('Image No.{} has average mean square error of {} and the average PSNR is {}'.format(index,meanerror,psnr))
```

Doing it this way lets me loop every video frame I have in the previous numpy array to perform my operation to calculate psnr.

What you could do is to try write your code to get the RGB values into a function using,

```
txtfilename = input("enter filename: ")
with open(str(txtfilename)+".txt","w") as results:
    for index in tqdm(range(0, len(img)))    #the array from imread
    img = cv2.imread('img', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    px = img[width, height]
    print("The RBG values are {}".format(px), file=results)
```

Something along the lines of this I guess, hope it helps.